# Expand div to the right on paragraph child growth

Tags: html, css

If i have a paragraph inside a div, is it possible to make the div expand to the left instead of to the right, when the paragraph gets longer? I know there are several threads on this, and i have tried with direction: rtl etc, but nothing seems to work for me.

Here is some code.

https://codepen.io/haa123/pen/oNxaqwE

HTML:

```
<div id="container">  
  <div id="container1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<br>
<div id="container2">
    <p>Expanding to the right</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  position: absolute; left: 50%;
}

#container1 {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container2 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here are some photos to illustrate.

This is what I have at the moment:

[image: Two red boxes on the left-hand side]

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: Two red boxes on the right-hand side]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.bricklet {text-align: right}
.bricklet .content {display: inline-block}
.bricklet .content.hidden {display: none}

<div class="bricklet">
  <div>Expander</div>
  <div class="content hidden">Expanded content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use css grid:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div></div>
  <div><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
  <div><p>expand</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like a CSS-related answer; can you post some of it?

Comment: I would like to see some CSS here too.

Comment: or flex box:
#container {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

#container1 {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container2 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

Comment: I highly reccomend this course on udemy: https://www.udemy.com/course/css-the-complete-guide-incl-flexbox-grid-sass

Answer (score 0):

You can use display flex in your container

```css
#container {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

#container1 {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container2 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">  
  <div id="container1">
        <p>Lorem aaabcdedfqafasafasfafasf</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="container2">
        <p>Expanding to the right asadasdsaqweqweqweqe</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was playing with flex yesterday, and it seems like it was the way to go. Thank you very much!

Comment: But is it possible to do it with only one element inside the main container? If i remove container1, its not working.

Comment: Although my answer is not the correct one, I want to explain why it is not working with only one element inside container, it is because i have forgotten to set the width for the container that are using position absolute combine with display flex, the width is needed to be set for it to work. You can read the documentation about [position absolute in display flex here.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you used `Position:absolute;` But if it is really necessary to use it, just by giving `text-aligen: right;` to your `#container`, your paragraph will be rtl.

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}

#container1 {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container2 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="container1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="container2">
    <p>Expanding to the right</p>
  </div>
```